# How to invoke Google Account Linking in test?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to set up account linking for a Google action which will use `Authorization Code` grant type to send a request to our internal OAuth infrastructure exposing `/login` and `/token` endpoints. According to [account linking docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2?oauth=code), the request will look something like:

```
GET https://myservice.example.com/auth?client_id=GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&state=STATE_STRING&scope=REQUESTED_SCOPES&response_type=code
```

We have similar infrastructure setup for similar kind of testing for Alexa skill, and the behavior between Alexa skills and Google actions seems to differ, so I have several questions related to those diffs:

- In Alexa simulator, I'm able to see the generated request

  https://liber.serveo.net/login?client_id=clientId&response_type=code&state=A2SAAEAEP-I65irPsd22zdGqok2JO8B...&scope=profile&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpitangui.amazon.com%2Fapi%2Fskill%2Flink%2FMRVW7BSUF428Q

with all relevant OAuth parameters (`client_id, response_type, state, scope & redirect_uri`) after clicking `Save Permissions` button during disabling/re-enabling skill flow:

[image]

- How can I enable a similar intercept of the generated request in Google Actions simulator?

I have configured a similar setup in Action's Account Linking tab:

[image]

however it doesn't seem to redirect to the `/login` endpoint of our OAuth server.  I'd like to understand why that is the case, so in order to see which required parameters might be missing from the generated redirect to the `/login` endpoint, I need to be able to intercept/see it.

I'm suspecting the request is not being sent at all, because account linking is not working as expected, but I want to be able to prove it definitively for which I'd like to be able to intercept the request.

- Is there a **specific user action** on Google simulator **to trigger sending of that login request** (akin to `Save Permissions` button in Alexa) or it must always be triggered from the webhook's code?
- Can we test account linking against our own OAuth provider **without** even **having a Dialogflow webhook** coded?
- I'm assuming GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, REDIRECT_URI, STATE_STRING, REQUESTED_SCOPES as documented per above don't have to necessarily be Google's and could instead be our own.  Is that a correct assumption or does the client id always have to be Google's?

Comment: There's no account linking button in the simulator, but you should be able to use the [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) for debugging. The client ID is that ID which you put in the console.

Comment: I don't quite get what this `OAuth playground` buys me or how to use it in my context, as I said we are using our own OAuth provider.  So, how do I see the formed URL?